# npm audit | debug Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity vulnerability - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-9vvw-cc9w-f27h

Tags: node.js, npm

```
# npm audit report
debug  <3.1.0
debug Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity vulnerability - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-9vvw-cc9w-f27h
No fix available
node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/debug
node_modules/express/node_modules/debug
node_modules/finalhandler/node_modules/debug
node_modules/send/node_modules/debug
  body-parser  >=1.12.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of debug
  node_modules/body-parser
    express  >=3.4.5
    Depends on vulnerable versions of body-parser
    Depends on vulnerable versions of debug
    Depends on vulnerable versions of finalhandler
    Depends on vulnerable versions of send
    Depends on vulnerable versions of serve-static
    node_modules/express
      inversify-express-utils  *
      Depends on vulnerable versions of express
      node_modules/inversify-express-utils
  finalhandler  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of debug
  node_modules/finalhandler
  send  0.3.0 - 0.18.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of debug
  node_modules/send
    serve-static  1.1.0 - 1.15.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of send
    node_modules/serve-static
7 low severity vulnerabilities
Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```

No fix available? What can i do to fix the problem. Must i downgrade packages? What is the exact Problem here? Pls can some one help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the debug module. Go to your package-lock.json and package.json and change the version to the latest one (4.3.4).

Comment: package-lock.json was the most important clue for me. many thanks

Comment: getting this problem on 4.3.4